# How to read HTML on another page and store in current page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I would like to read data from another page. It has a heap of `<a href= .... >`

The purpose is to be able to sort and select these links within another page.
So I need to be able to request the data from another page and store it there. So that it can then be sorted with javascript.

It all needs to be done client-side. I can make use of libraries such as jQuery/ajax.

Comment: Are both `html` documents on same domain ?

Comment: Yes. I believe if it were not, then client-side is not possible.

Comment: Ajax isn't a library.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.load()` with name of `html` page followed by selector `a` to load all `a` elements found at `/other/html/page` into a parent element container

```
$(selector).load("/other/html/page a")
```

Comment: So could that parent element be pretty much of any type, such as an array?